# how to add path?

Tags: command-line

I am trying to complete the installation for some software. According to which I have to add path. I am not getting it how to do that. Please guide me how to do the following steps.

Add the path to Rpa/Tk headers:

```
 -I/usr/include/rpatk
```

To link to the Rpa/Tk libraries on Linux add the following link options:

```
-lrpa -lrvm -lrex -lrlib -lm
```

RVM library uses some math functions from the system math library, that is why you must include '-lm' to include the math library to your project in addition to the Rpa/Tk built libraries:

librpa
librex
librvm
librlib

http://www.rpasearch.com/rpatk/doc/doxygen/rpadoc/html/rpatk_build.html

Comment: Take a look at this [Post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path), it might help.

Answer (score 1):

These instructions are telling you how to compile another package using the package that you've installed. Technically, the installation is already complete, and you only need to follow these instructions later when you want to compile something else. Is there another package that you want to install that uses this one?

The special strings from the instructions are just command line arguments to gcc. For example, if you wrote a C program that used rpatk in a file called `test.c`, you would run this to compile it:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/rpatk -lrpa -lrvm -lrex -lrlib -lm -o test test.c
```

Comment: okay but please do tell me how to do the above steps. Which commands do I need to use?

Comment: Those are just command line arguments to gcc. I've updated my answer with more information.

Comment: Okay thanks but one more thing when I give the command make (to build php extension). I get such type of commands on my console :  /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/librpa.a when searching for -lrpa
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../librpa.a when searching for -lrpa
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/librpa.a when searching for -lrpa
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrpa
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../lib/librvm.a when searching for -lrvm

Comment: Try pasting that error into google; it looks like you've installed 32-bit libraries on a 64-bit system or vice versa. Either way this would be better to resolve in a separate question rather than comments on an answer to another question.

Comment: Thank u for pointing it out. I accidentally installed 64 bit libraries...